# How can I find the installation details for an existing SDL Tridion installation?

Tags: 2011, content-delivery

Where should I look to find the installation details for an existing SDL Tridion installation?

Is there any way to get the following details from any of the config files for the Tridion installation?

1. Tridion Installation version details for both the Content Manager and Content Delivery
2. Database details
3. Server details (IIS version etc)

Comment: I am a little unclear as to exactly what you are asking for. Are you asking how to find out the details of a current Tridion Install?

Comment: @GlennStevens. Yes, I want to find the details of current install like the version content manager and content delivery and database being used etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not sure why do you want to get this information from the Tridion Config file but you may follow below steps to get the versions -

**For Content Manager:** you can check the "About SDL Tridion" tab in the Dashboard as shown below

[image]

Alternatively, you may click on the top-right corner SDL | Tridion text to open a pop-up and see the version as shown below:

[image]

**For Content Delivery:** You need to rely on the size (or versions) of the DLLs and JAR files as far as I know.

**For Database:** you may need to go to the DB Server and check the version in installed DBMS package and the process may depend on the OS in use (Linux/Unix or Windows)

**UPDATE:** If it is MS-SQL Server then you may run the SQL command -

`SELECT @@VERSION` or

`SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('productversion'), SERVERPROPERTY ('productlevel'), SERVERPROPERTY ('edition')`

to get the version and other details of DB server.

**For IIS:** Go to the CM Server and open the IIS Manager and from Help menu choose the About IIS as shown below:

[image]

In Addition, each Windows comes with its own IIS and if you know the OS version, then getting the IIS version is fun. Below is the mapping table: (NOTE: per my kowledge, post Windows Server 2000, IIS can not be upgraded without upgrading the OS)

- Windows Server 2000      - IIS 5.0
- Windows XP Professional  - IIS 5.1
- Windows Server 2003      - IIS 6.0
- Windows Vista            - IIS 7.0
- Windows Server 2008      - IIS 7.0
- Windows Server 2008 R2   - IIS 7.5
- Windows 7                - IIS 7.5
- Windows Server 2012      - IIS 8.0
- Windows 8                - IIS 8.0

Answer (score 4):

In order to know which tridion version you are using you can check it in the DLL Versions and config files versions. For Tridion 2013 it will say 7.0, for 2011 it will say 6.1 or 6.0 depending on the Service Pack you have installed.

For the database details, you will need to access your database server.

For IIS you will need to access to your IIS Server

Additionally if you check the Tridion Install requirements you can see the database and iis required versions for an specific tridion version.