# Tridion (2013-sp1) what hot fixes are installed?

Tags: 2013, 2013-sp1

Apart from checking the Tridion CMS / About SDL Tridion page, how can I check what hot fixes are installed?

Specifically I'm interested to check if HR1 was installed in an instance of Tridion 2013-SP1.

For reference in the About SDL Tridion page it shows:

- Content Manager - Build 7.1.0
- Content Manager Explorer - Build 7.1.0.66
- Experience Manager - Build 7.1.0.79
- Update Version - SP1

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you are using SP1 only not HR1. Here is the screen grab for about screen from the SDL Tridion 2013 HR1.
Also there is 
[image]

Hope you are also aware of [Hotfix Manager](https://sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/HotfixManager.aspx) to manage all your SDL Tridion fix.

Comment: Thanks Vikas for the information and the useful screen grab.

Comment: I have to disagree with the above answer. Build 7.1.0.66 is indeed Tridion 2013 SP1 HR1. Not just SP1

Answer (score 2):

HR1 is basically a collection of all the major hotfix released in the previous version. For example, Tridion 2013 SP1 HR1 would cover all the major hotfixes in Tridion 2013 SP1. When you first run the HR1 Content Manager installer, it will show you all the hotfix with its hotfix id in the splash screen. Beside that, SDL Live doc should have documentation on the list of hotfixes HR1 covers

Answer (score 2):

As Vikas says, it appears from your version number that you are using **SDL Tridion 2013 SP1** but **not HR1**.

I don't have an instance with HR1 installed on, but if previous versions of Tridion are anything to go by, then the if HR1 is installed then this should display in the 'About' page.

For example, please see the screenshot below (from @Pankaj's answer here: https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/3074/71).

[image]

Alternatively, if you can find out the exact DLL and JAR file version numbers that are expected for HR1 (Nuno or someone 'internal' may know these) then you can use the tools in [Dominic's answer to "Find the version build numbers for SDL Tridion 2013 sp1"](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/4757/71) to find the [JAR file](https://code.google.com/p/tridion-practice/wiki/CheckVersionsOfContentDeliveryJars) and DLL file versions on your server.

Although these techniques should tell you whether a **Hotfix Rollup** is installed, **they may not tell you the details of any additional hotfixes that have been added outside of any rollup**. For example, [Hotfix CME_2013.1.0.87658](https://www.sdltridionworld.com/downloads/hotfixes/SDL_Tridion_2013_SP1/index.aspx) updates a JavaScript file on the server, which has no easily discoverable version numbering.

**You will need to keep track of additional hotfixes installed yourself.** There are three common techniques for this:

1. As Vikas mentions, you could do this using the [Hotfix Manager](https://sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/HotfixManager.aspx) tool from SDL Tridion World.
2. You could use a shared spreadsheet to log all the details of any hotfixes applied, or
3. You could store all hotfixes that have been applied in a shared folder. However, this would not give the order in which they have been applied!